# Best way to create a safe 'blocking loop' that waits for a variable changed by another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

In a nutshell, I have a PCB that controls a motor with an encoder (so I can read its 'position' or count). In my (C#) software, there are times I need to tell the motor to move to a certain position and wait for it to get there before the procedure continues.

I am using .net 3.5 so can't use the await/async features, what is my best alternative?

Using a loop such as:

```
while (motorPositon != motorDestination) continue;
```

Doesn't work - it causes a hanging loop which uses 100% of CPU and never registers changes to `motorDestination`. This doesn't really surprise me, but adding the dreaded `Application.DoEvents()` to the loop helps - on some (fast) computers at least. Furthermore, adding a `Thread.Sleep(x)` call to the loop seems to make it work as desired on slower computers.

However, this 'fix' makes me feel very uncomfortable and I'm sure there must be a better way.

I have thought about using a timer to check motorPosition instead of the loop, but this also feels clumsy to me.

Is there a trick I'm missing? This seems like it must be a common issue, but my searches so far haven't yielded any particularly satisfying answers.

**edit**: `motorPosition` is read/updated by regular polling calls to the PCB (this is done with a timer).

Comment: First of all - don't cheat - use proper locking to access shared values. When you get code working with busy loop you have start reading on OS level events (C# - [Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) ).

Comment: Rhetorical question maybe, but if you did have await/async, what would you wait for? Maybe your question is missing some clues about how your program interacts with the PCB?

Comment: @RenniePet updated question. I have a timer which continually requests the motor position and updates the static variable motorPosition

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I appreciate what you're saying, but can't help wondering how essential that is to this situation. As I am not modif>?ying the variable outside of the thread shouldn't this avoid race conditions anyway? And even if the variable was lock()d, this wouldn't stop a while()continue; loop from using all the cpu, right?

Comment: Why not use the **Interlocked** methods such as **Interlocked.Read()** together with **Thread.Sleep()**?

Comment: It's difficult to advise without knowing a lot more about your program and it's interfacing with the PCB. But when you already have one timer that is involved with polling the PCB, maybe that code should be enhanced to also optionally test for the desired position, and then Set an AutoResetEvent that the main thread is waiting on? (This assumes the timer you're talking about is running on a separate thread.)

Comment: @RenniePet I understand it's difficult to comment without a deeper knowledge, but you may be right. However, I am somewhat reluctant to extend the timer method as mentioned; effectively the timer is a state management tool which just checks numerous values and updates static variables in the software accordingly. It seems sensible to me to keep this separate from any 'controlling' parts of the software, but maybe adding delegates/events to be triggered when certain values are reached is a good way to go?

Comment: @MickyDuncan a big part of my original concern was regarding the usage of Thread.Sleep() to force other threads to update. Is this an acceptable thing to do?

Comment: Is the timer running on a separate thread?

Comment: @RenniePet I'm fairly sure it is, yes. Using Thread.Sleep() works and allows the variable to be updated before it is compared, and also stops the 100% cpu issue. But this feels like a cheap trick?

Comment: OK, if the timer is running on a separate thread, then I'll stand by my recommendation re using an AutoResetEvent that your main program does a WaitOne() on, and getting the timer code to do a Set() on the AutoResetEvent to wake up the main program. The nuts and bolts of how little or how much you have to change the timer code to get this to work, and whether it can be made to fit in with the overall ambiance of the timer code, is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: PS. Thread.Sleep() is not involved.

Comment: Trying to reason how non-lock'ed access to variables would work in multiple threads case is entertaining, but not very productive. How good is your understanding of memory barriers, operation reordering and compiler/JIT optimizations? Reading your post I have feeling that you may not have very deep understanding of the topic (happy to be wrong), so that why I suggesting to use code style that is  known to behave correctly before trying lock-free approaches.

Comment: @Alfie how come you're 'fairly sure' that the timer runs on another thread? Do you have no control over the timer code or the instantiation? Anyway, ReniePet's advice is right on the money, either Thread.Sleep and poll if you're single threaded and have no way raise any kind of event when the motor is in position, or AutoReset and WaitOne if you're on separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be ideal if the hardware itself could raise an interrupt that you could handle, and maybe main thread waits on an event that the interrupt sets. But it sounds like that might not be possible in your situation.

I would use a BackgroundWorker where the DoWork handler would so something like:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
while (motorPosition != motorDestination)
{
  if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
    break;
  }
  Thread.Sleep(500)
}
```

Since the thread is a background thread, your main UI thread should be fine. You won't kill the CPU as your thread only processes twice a second (increase the sleep if it makes sense). And it supports cancel, should you need it. (You might want to tell the motor to stop moving as well, if it is cancelled.)

Then in the RunWorkerCompleted handler, which will run in the main UI thread, you can pick up and do whatever comes next.

Comment: Note that you are not addressing problem specified in the main post - changes from other thread are not available (and possibly ignored by JITed code altogether).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your solution seems similar to the working code I have at the moment (while loop which includes a Thread.Sleep() call). Is this really a good method?

Comment: @Alfie No, the Thread.Sleep() is not ideal. I believe that the ideal is still hardware raising an interrupt. But IF you don't have any control over the hardware, that may not be an option. Thread.Sleep() is not really all that different than a Timer that signals every so often. In both cases, you will have a construct that doesn't take any CPU cycles except when it checks the state of the hardware, and in both cases it will not be blocking the main thread. They are both decent solutions.